# User Points by OG

Tags: views, organic-groups, userpoints

I activiated the quiz module. Then users can earn points after answering some questions in the quiz. Now I want to have a view to show a list of all group members with their profile attributes and their earned points to the group onwer. I searched for a solution from internet, but without success.  I really appreciate if you could show the steps to implement this functionality. Thanks a lot!!